# Why I can't get value by using doReturn in Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito

I had a method in mock service,

```
def whenDynamoDBActionBlacklist(newlist: List[String]) = {
    doReturn(newlist).when(service).Blacklist
  }
```

and want to test it by using

```
val list = mocks.whenDynamoDBActionBlacklist(List("333:avd"))
```

but I can't get the value, got the nullPointerException, can anyone help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are confusing the difference between mock *setup* and mock *execution*. `whenDynamoDBActionBlacklist` does not actually return a value, instead in just specifies responses for the stubbed methods. Consider the following example

```
import org.mockito.{ArgumentMatchersSugar, IdiomaticMockito}
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class MockitoScalaExampleSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with IdiomaticMockito with ArgumentMatchersSugar {
  "MockitoScalaExample" should "demonstrated difference between mock setup and mock execution" in {

    // system under test
    trait MyService {
      def blacklist: List[String]
    }

    // initialise mock of the system under test
    val serviceMock = mock[MyService]

    // specify behaviour of the mock by defining how should stubbed methods respond
    serviceMock.blacklist returns List("mocked!")

    // actually execute the mocked system under test
    val result = serviceMock.blacklist

    // assert on the result
    result should be(List("mocked!"))
  }
}
```

The key is to understand

```
serviceMock.blacklist returns List("mocked!")
```

does not yet return `List("mocked!")` but it declares what should happen once we call `aMock.blacklist`.

<sub>Note the example uses [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#idiomatic-mockito) but the same concepts apply in vanilla Mockito</sub>.

Comment: I'm still little confused..So how to make serviceMock.blacklist actually return a thing?
"
val result = serviceMock.blacklist
"
this step?

Comment: @alexx Yes `result` holds mock's response.